# How to limit the quantity of selected checkboxes and pass values to a different page using PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Sorry for my noobness here I'm trying to create a project with no PHP knowledge at all.

I have a database set up with a list of users and I am able to display users based on specific information through a search. Each search query has a checkbox. What I am trying to do now is limit the amount of selected checkboxes (up to 3 selections only) and save the selected queries to a different page. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm sure my code is all over the place and probably wrong in many ways so I apologise in advance. I appreciate it.

Search Results Page:

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php'; 
    protect_page();
    include 'includes/overall/overallheader.php'; 
?>

<h1>New Staff Request</h1>

<p>Search for potential staff using the form below</p>


<form method="POST">
    <input type="TEXT" name="search" />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<br/>

<p><b> Select only up to 3 results</b></p>
<form method="post" action="StaffingRequest.php">
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','lr');
            $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
            $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE jobcat LIKE '%$search%' ");
            if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
                while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $rows['last_name'];
                    $education = $rows['education'];
                    $salary = $rows['salary'];
                    $jobcat = $rows['jobcat'];
                    echo "<br /><input type='checkbox' name='query[]' value=''> First Name: $first_name<br />Last Name: $last_name<br />Job Category: $jobcat<br />Education: $education<br />Salary: $salary<br /><br />";
                }
            } else {
                echo "No Results";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Save">
</form>

<?php include 'includes/overall/overallfooter.php'; ?>
```

Here is the page I want the results to display on:

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php'; 
    protect_page();

    include 'includes/overall/overallheader.php';
?>
      <h1>My Staff Requests:</h1>
      <p></p>
<?php

    $chkbox = $_POST['query'];
    $i = 0;
    While($i < sizeof($chkbox)) {
        echo "CheckBox Selected Values = " . $chkbox[$i] . '</br>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
<?php include 'includes/overall/overallfooter.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use JS/jQuery to accomplish this.

What you are going to do is add some client side functionality that checks how many check boxes of the same class have a check in them.

I added the code for you. This is what it does.

- Add the jQuery library.
- Add a classname (class="checkboxes") to the input tag to be referenced later.
- Detect when there has been a change to an element with the class name "checkboxes".
- Count to see how many elements with the class name "checkboxes" have a checked checkbox.
- If there are three checked check boxes, remove the check from the last(4th) selected check box.
- Display an error to the user that only three check boxes can be selected.

Like so:

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php'; 
    protect_page();
    include 'includes/overall/overallheader.php'; 
?>

<h1>New Staff Request</h1>

<p>Search for potential staff using the form below</p>


<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="TEXT" name="search" />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<br/>

<p><b> Select only up to 3 results</b></p>
<form method="POST" action="StaffingRequest.php">
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','lr');
            $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
            $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE jobcat LIKE '%$search%' ");
            if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
                while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $rows['last_name'];
                    $education = $rows['education'];
                    $salary = $rows['salary'];
                    $jobcat = $rows['jobcat'];
                    echo '<br /><input type="checkbox" name="query[]" class="checkboxes" value=""> First Name: ' . $first_name . '<br />Last Name: ' . $last_name . '<br />Job Category: ' .  $jobcat . '<br />Education: ' . $education . '<br />Salary: ' . $salary . '<br /><br />';

                    }
            } else {
                echo "No Results";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Save">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".checkboxes").change(function (){

    if($('.checkboxes:checkbox:checked').length > 3){

      $(this).prop('checked', false);
      alert("You can only select 3 checkboxes.");

    }

  });


});

</script>

<?php include 'includes/overall/overallfooter.php'; ?>
```

A couple other things.

- I try real hard not to have more than one form on a page.  For the most part you should only need one.  I would say that if you have two forms it's a special case.  Your first form that you use for the search could easily be replaced with an AJAX routine.
- When echoing HTML though PHP, I recommend using single quotes.  This will prevent alot of problems dealing with the quotes for the elements attributes. Here is an example of how I do it:

  echo `'<input id="myId">Test</input>';`

This will save you some headaches down the road.

Hope this works for you..